# How to add up the numbers in a column?

Tags: php, mysql

```
id  |  number
1   |    10
2   |    24
3   |    45
4   |    25
5   |    12
```

How can I get the sum of all numbers in the `number` column?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(number) FROM table
```

Should do it.

If you only want to sum *some* of the numbers, or aggregate them by groups of IDs, or some other thing, then you'll need to learn about `WHERE` or `GROUP BY` clauses. :)

Answer (score 1):

Should just be SELECT SUM(number) FROM table.

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlsum.php has a nifty tutorial

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(number) from table ...
```

try the code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(number)
from yourtable
```

You'll want to look at MySQL's [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) to see what all's available.